# How to check for the existence of an action within a namespace in Struts2?

Tags: struts2, namespaces, action

I'd like to implement in a Struts2 web application some sort of url "fallback" using an own ActionMapper. This means:

when

> http://server/webapp/foo/bar/myaction

does not exist, I want the ActionMapper to try to load e.g.

> http://server/webapp/foo_fallback/bar/myaction

instead.

Parsing the URL and therefore finding the namespace is not a problem, but I don't know how to decide if the desired action is present in this namespace (which I have to modify if it is not).

Is there a possibility to check if an action exists within a namespace (/foo/bar in this case)? Or is there another mechanism to perform what I intend to do?

Thanks,

Gregor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. This happens in the custom ActionMapper:

To find out if an action exists, I firstly construct a string of the class name (including the namespace) of the desired action. Then I call

```
Class.forName("namespaceroot.foo.bar.myaction");
```

If the action does not exist, an `ClassNotFoundException` exception is thrown, which I can check for in a `try { ... } catch { ... }` block. Within the `catch` block I can change the namespace of the mapping to the fallback namespace. This has some implications to the `ActionProxy`: The namespace has to be changed there, too, in `getMappingFromActionName`. Otherwise the `ActionProxy` contains the namespace of the request, which is fine usually. The `DefaultActionProxy` does not have a setter for namespace, so I subclassed it and create it using a custom `AxtionProxyFactory`. Phew.

This is not elegant imho, but as long as I don't come up with a better idea it'll stay that way. I'd love to hear a better solution!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this for every configured namespace:

```
<action name="*">
    <result type="redirectAction">your fallback action here</result>
</action>
```

If it doesn't work, set `struts.enable.SlashesInActionNames` to `false`.

Comment: If I understand you correctly this would perform a fallback action. What I need is a fallback /namespace/.

However, I solved it using a custom ActionMapper and changing the namespace if needed in the getMapping() method. The ActionProxy has to get the new namespace as well, so I extended it by adding a setter for namespace. Hopefully this does not remind you of http://xkcd.com/763/ :)